# does php-list have any api for integration to other softwares

Tags: phplist

I've tried searching their forums and going through their documentation. But I didn't find any information on how to integrate php-list with an existing web-app.

It's a complete new software in itself, with new users and everything. I need to create users, add/remove them from lists using some form of REST or other integration.

As far as I've searched, there's a means to add someone to a list, using a single http-request. But I didn't find means to remove someone from such a list.

I also found out there are plugins etc. for various CMSes for integration.

But I have a java-webapp and looking for something easy to implement, otherwise the only way I see is to use htmlunit (or similar tool) to send requests for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it **does not have API** for integration with other apps. I had to develop a custom phplist integration API for my employer.

Comment: Is that a kind of public API (good documentation) ? Is it on git-hub ? Can you put it up there ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Official REST API Plugin](https://resources.phplist.com/plugin/restapi), its based on the plugin by [Andreas Ek](https://github.com/EkAndreas/phplistapi)